# Scrapy: TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm making a spider using Scrapy (1.1.2) to scrap products. I managed to get it to work and scrape enough data, but now, I want for each element to make new request to the `product page` and scrap, for example the product description.

First, here's my last working code

**spider.py** (except)

```
class ProductScrapSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com/index.php?id_category=24"
        # ...
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("a long string"):
            mainloader = ProductLoader(selector=sel)
            mainloader.add_value('category', 'Category Name')
            mainloader.add_value('meta', self.get_meta(sel))
            # more data

            yield mainloader.load_item()

            # Follows the pagination
            next_page = response.css("li#pagination_next a::attr('href')")
            if next_page:
                url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
                yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

    def get_meta(self, response):
        metaloader = ProductMetaLoader(selector=response)
        metaloader.add_value('store', "Store name")
        # more data

        yield metaloader.load_item()
```

**Output**

```
[
 {
     "category": "Category Name",
     "price": 220000,
     "meta": {
         "baseURL": "",
         "name": "",
         "store": "Store Name"
     },
     "reference": "100XXX100"
 },
 ...
]
```

After reading the documentation and some answers here, I've altered the `get_meta` method and added a callback for the request `get_product_page`:

**new_spider.py** (except)

```
def get_meta(self, response):
    metaloader = ProductMetaLoader(selector=response)
    metaloader.add_value('store', "Store name")
    # more data

    items = metaloader.load_item()
    new_request = scrapy.Request(items['url'], callback=self.get_product_page)

    # Passing the metadata
    new_request.meta['item'] = items

    # The source of the problem
    yield new_request

def get_product_page(self, response):
    sel = response.selector.css('.product_description')
    items = response.meta['item']

    new_meta = items
    new_meta.update({'product_page': sel[0].extract()})

    return new_meta
```

**Expected output**

```
[
 {
     "category": "Category Name",
     "price": 220000,
     "meta": {
         "baseURL": "",
         "name": "",
         "store": "Store Name",
         "product_page": "<div> [...] </div>" 
     },
     "reference": "100XXX100"
 },
 ...
]
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable
```

[full output](http://pastebin.com/napscirN)

I couldn't find anything about this error, so please help me fix it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where is `get_meta` invoked? Did you try returning a new request object inside an item pipeline?

Comment: Sorry, I added missing call for `get_meta` inside Item Field `meta`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you experience (`TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable`) happened because a `Request` instance is being put into a field of the item (in the updated `get_meta` method function), while the feed exporter cannot serialize it.

You would need to return the get meta request to Scrapy, together with a meta argument to pass the half-parsed item. Here's an example of the updated `parse` method and a new `parse_get_meta` method:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath("a long string"):
        mainloader = ProductLoader(selector=sel)
        mainloader.add_value('category', 'Category Name')
        #mainloader.add_value('meta', self.get_meta(sel))
        # more data
        item = mainloader.load_item()
        get_meta_req = self.get_meta(sel)
        get_meta_req['meta']['item'] = item
        yield get_meta_req.replace(callback=self.parse_get_meta)

def parse_get_meta(self, response):
    """Parses a get meta response"""
    item = response.meta['item']
    # Parse the response and load the data here, e.g. item['foo'] = bar
    pass
    # Finally return the item
    return item
```

See also: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments

Comment: The two methods `parse_get_meta` and `get_product_page` were overlapping, so it was confusing to adapt your approach in my code, the engine was actually sending requests but without retrieving anything. The output is slightly different with all the key aligned as I also had to modifiy the Item class inside the `items.py`. Did I mention it works.